# SQL NULL equals and not equals NULL

Tags: sql

I know `NULL` in SQL is an unknown value so `NULL` is not equal to `NULL`, since both are unknown but I was expecting the second `IF` here to return `not eq`, instead it returns `eq`. Why? What am I missing? Why do they both evaluate to else?

```
declare @i int = null
declare @i2 int = null

if @i = @i2 select 'eq' else select 'not eq'
if @i <> @i2 select 'not eq' else select 'eq'
```

Comment: Which database are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: Never tested this point, but try `!=` instead of `<>`.

Comment: @GurV MsSQL 2016 although I'm not sure if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

At its simplest, this can be explained by:

1. The value of `NULL` is unknown (or the value doesn't exist)
2. On that basis, the value of any comparison involving a `NULL` (e.g. equality `=`, inequality `<>`, greater/lesser than '>') all evaluate to a result of unknown (i.e. `NULL` itself). So, both `@i = @i2` and `@i <> @i2` return the same `Unknown` or `NULL` result.
3. Since `NULL` or unknown is not `True`, control always branches to the `ELSE` block and never to the `THEN` block.

Comment: Makes sense. Any idea how I could confirm `@i <> @i2`is `NULL`?

Comment: @curious - run a `print (@i <> @i2)` to see what the expression evaluates to.

Answer (score 0):

`NULL` is a known value in SQL (and most character sets).

In your Question after substituting in the variables, your second test equates to `NULL <> NULL`.  Since something is neither larger nor smaller than itself your test returns false, thus the `SELECT` returns `eq`.

Note : Some functions as well as some operations may return `NULL` if they encounter an unrecognised or invalid value.  Thus even when the value does not equal `NULL` the value of the *function* may do so. i.e. Where `value <> NULL`, `FUNCTION_1( value ) = NULL` may still be true.

Comment: According to your answer, the OP's first query should return `eq` instead of `not eq` which doesn't happen. The comparison operation can only be done on the known values and not on unknown. For NULL, you can use only IS NULL or IS NOT NULL.

Comment: The Questioner only refers to the second test, not the first.  I am assuming that the first test is performing as expected, namely that it is returning `eq`.

Comment: The first query won't return `eq', it will return 'not eq'. And both this query results are going to else part because of the same reason. If you don't agree with me, just run both the queries.